# ARM conditional instruction setting flags

Tags: arm, arm64

As I read about conditional execution in ARM, I can see why instructions in ARM do not set the flags by default. They seem to set flags only when the `S` suffix is added in. I was wondering if it would be possible to have an ARM instruction that executes conditionally, but also sets flags. Could you give me an example for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ARM instruction executes conditionally (unless the condition code is `AL` for always). Any condition code is allowed on any instruction.

Comment: well...that is not true, the traditional 32 bit arm instruction set sure, but thumb, thumb2 extensions and the 64 bit architecture do not (note the arm64 tag in the question).  Jazelle, a couple-three formats of floating point, etc are also part of the general arm instruction set.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to both execute conditionally and set the flags, for example

```
ADDSCS  r0, r1, r2    ; If C flag set then r0 = r1 + r2, and update flags
```